# Dependency management for web extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dependency-management, firefox-addon-webextensions

A file from one of my extensions has been copied, so that three of them now share [a common code file](https://github.com/serv-inc/YouTube-Filter/blob/master/addon/settings.js). (It's for accessing managed storage, with a fallback).

Keeping this updated to all extensions by copying is a bit tedious, as changes to one are not automatically applied to the other.

**What is a clean way to use the same `.js` file  in several web extensions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the good approach is to publish your file as an npm package, use it as a dependency and update in other extensions using [greenkeeper](https://greenkeeper.io/). So then you can build extensions via any Continuous Integration (CI) service and even upload it using [Chrome Webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. Any pointers on how to create a npm package?

Comment: It is a minute or less: take a look documentation about [publishing packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)